# Need to redirect from Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page to home page in wordpress

Tags: redirect, subdomains

I have a subdomain like https://faq.example.com/faq this page works fine.
changed URL like main domain https://example.com/faq this also works fine.
But when I go to this page https://faq.example.com it shows Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page like below,
[image]

My requirements are https://faq.example.com this page needs to redirect to https://example.com/faq this page.

Please share the idea to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your apache should be configured to serve a specific folder as root for this subdomain, did you check this out already? It should be quite straight forward to put a .htaccess in there (or even put the rules directly in the config for the subdomain/virtualhost).

Comment: Am not able to understand can you please explain in detail so that I can able to fix this issue.

Comment: can i delete the root directory index.html from the server attached image below to fix this issue.
https://ibb.co/xF0t3sN